# CocoaTouch - iPhone App - Showing dialogbox before execution continues

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

when a user taps on an image in the iPhone App page, I want to first show a custom pop-up (which is a user message saying "your request is being processed"), "before" beginning the processing of the image-touch. But, somehow the processing begins (without even displaying the pop-up, though I have written the code to display the pop-up 'before' the processing code) & almost ends, & only then the pop-up is displayed. Can you please help?

This is the code snippet :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    int emotionChosen = -1;
    [self showUserNote:msg];
    ...
    ...
    // This then calls a method to process the touch event
    ...
    ...
}

-(void) showUserNote:(NSString *)note {

    if ((self.viewCtrlrUserNote == nil) || (self.viewCtrlrUserNote == NULL)) {
        self.viewCtrlrUserNote = (ViewController_NoteToUser *) [((com_AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kNameViewCtrlrUserNote];
    }
    [self.viewCtrlrUserNote.view setFrame:CGRectMake(70.0,150.0,170.0,170.0)];
    [self.viewCtrlrUserNote initializeViewWithNote:note];
    [self.view addSubview:self.viewCtrlrUserNote.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.viewCtrlrUserNote.view];
}
```

Though am making the call to showUserNote (which should display the pop-up/dialogbox) "first", "and then only" am calling the method which processes the touch. But the method to process the touch begins execution first & the dialog box appears only near the end of  the processing-method, & so it destroys the very purpose!

My Dev Environment : XCode 4.3.3, iPad, iOS 5

How do I "mandate" it that iOS "first" displays the user dialog "before" beginning to process the touch event?

Comment: Can you explain why the specific order is important?  The typical design kicks off the background work and presents "working on it" UI status in the same turn of the run loop.  Both things actually start happening when the app returns, and most of the time that's what people want.  What happens in your processTouch code to spoil the UI change?

Comment: So is the issue that the processing code takes a long time, and you'd like to show the user an alert to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing and UI commands are generally not synchronous in CocoaTouch (or indeed, in any modern graphics API that uses 3D acceleration and compositing). When you do all the work in `-showUserNote:` you are queuing up commands to the view subsystem to do all of those things the next time it processes events, not actually doing them.

The standard pattern to achieve what you want is to use delegation have it the view callback into the delegate once it has drawn. Apple uses this pattern in the UIAlert class, what you should do is get your code working using that instead of your custom view, then modify your custom view to have a delegate and call back into it once it has displayed.

I highly recommend you read up on [runloops](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) so you can understand event processing and things like deferred processing.

Comment: Thank you, Louis. That gives me a different perspective to think of the problem! let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try bundling the code you want to run after the dialogue into a separate method 
and calling it with an NSTimer (Also a good idea to check the dialog is working by // out the code afterward to check)
something like this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTouchEvent) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

where myTouchEvent is the method you would create.

@Lois Bergarg pointed out this will probably not work, which was my first thought....

```
  NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.5];
  [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
```

Comment: Please do not do any of this. It will not work. The first option will sleep the  thread you are on. You are probably on the main thread, so the effect will just be to introduce a user visible 0.5 second UI freeze and still have everything run before your view displays. The second will introduce a race condition that results in odd bugs and crashes if your timing guesses are off (for instance, if a phone call comes in during that 1.0 second between when you load the timer and it fires). Just design your classes to properly use delegation.

Comment: And since you reordered your post, everything I said above is still true, except the second bit of code is the one that definitely will not work, the first solution you provide is the one that will appear to work sometimes but introduce intermittent bugs and crashes due to it being a race condition.

Comment: You said it would cause some problems and not that it would not work,
I don't really want to argue with or offend you, but I think maybe a timing race doesn't seem to be a big issue if you are talking about setting an interval that is always the same. Honestly, I am not sure how it would react if you got a phone call in the interval set by the timer to delay the action though. 
I would definitely like to understand more about the answer you suggested, I understand delegation, but I am not sure what you mean to be done here, although it wasn't my question.
Anyways, thanks for your suggestions.